# How to run tests from within a python package directory?

Tags: python

I have a python package with a `tests` folder within it. There are also many relative imports used in the modules and tests folder.

```
my_package/
     __init__.py
    my_module.py
    my_helper/  
        __init__.py
        work.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_work.py
```

I would like to `cd my_package` and run `python -m unittest`.

This results in:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

This is because in `test_work.py`, it has a relative import: `from ..my_helper import work`.

I also printed in `test_work.py`:

```
print(__package__) ### tests
print(__name__)    ### tests.test_work
```

If I `cd ..` so I am no longer in `my_package` and run `python -m unittest` the tests run correctly.

With the following output when printing in `test_work.py`:

```
print(__package__) ### my_package.tests
print(__name__)    ### my_package.tests.test_work
```

This does not feel *right*, I want to be able to test and have my continuous integration test without having to `cd ..`. As this will test all modules found in the directory above.

How can I run `python -m unittest` or `nosetests` or `pytest` from within the package and have them run as a `__package__` with the correct hierachy?

Or is it not worth it and I have to test from the parent directory due to the current structure?

Answer (score 1):

## Project's folder layout

You should modify your folder layout to the [current recommended](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) (or see [pytest docu](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html)). And keep in mind that when you look around in the internet you always find outdated (and today wrong) information's about packaging python projects. Look on the dates of blog-posts, tutorials and docs! Good start is [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) documentation.

Always separate your package folder (where the `__init__.py` file is in) and the `tests` folder.

Because of that in your case you will need an extra project folder like this.

```
my_project/
    README
    setup.cfg
    ...
    my_package/
         __init__.py
         ...
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_work.py
```

### Improve with `src` layout

But read further to see how I would improve this with the so called `src`-layout.

## How to `import` in unittests?

Now you wonder how to `import` your package in your `test_*.py` files, right?
I assume that your `test_work.py` file looks like this:

```
from .. import my_module
# ...
```

Don't do this. Your goal should be just to do:

```
from my_package import my_module
```

### Install in Development Mode via `--editable`

How could this be done? You have to "install" your package in [Developement Mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html). Use the `--editable` option of `pip`. In that case not a real package is build and installed but only symlinks are used to expose your package folder (the source in developer version) to the operating system as it would be a real release package.

Now your unittest never need to care about where the package is installed and how to import it. Just import it because the package is known to the system.

## Example configuration

1. As an addition to my first Create the project folder and modify the folders inside it as I pointed out above.

   my_project/
   README
   setup.cfg
   ...
   src/
   my_package/
   **init**.py
   ...
   tests/
   **init**.py
   test_work.py
2. Create a `my_project/setup.cfg` with that content:

```
[metadata]
name = my_package

[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages = find:
zip_safe = False
python_requires = >= 3
[options.packages.find]
where = src
exclude =
    tests*
    .gitignore
```

3. Create `my_project/setup.py` with that content:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

4. Install the package in [Developement Mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html). Navigate into the project folder `my_project`. Run `python3 -m pip install --editable .`
5. Now modify the `import` statements in your `test_*.py` files.
6. Run your tests from the project folder `python3 -m unittest`.

Comment: In the case where the package is not setup as a proper python package - but as a `git submodule` imported into your project. How should testing be handled?

Comment: That depends on "who" should do the tests. IMHO a git repo that import's another project via `git submodule` shouldn't be responsible for testing this submodule. The submodule itself is responsible for that. But if you really need this just install the submodule in developer mode also. `--editable` is the recommended way. Don't do relative `imports` from your submodule like `from .submodule import`.

Comment: I agree the submodule is responsible and should be able to be tested standalone - but it is difficult as the tests folder is inside the module - not separate as per your recommended approach.

Comment: Then create a ticket to the submodule, modify it or choose another one. Ask yourself if you really need it as `git submodule` or just `git clone` and then install it via `pip --editable`.