# Can't do Python imports from another dir

Tags: python

I'm unable to import from Python file in another directory. Directory structure:

```
some_root/
  - __init__.py
  - dir_0/
    - __init__.py
    - dir_1/
      - __init__.py
      - file_1.py
    - dir_2/
      - __init__.py
      - file_2.py
```

`file_1.py` has some exported member:

```py
# file_1.py
def foo():
    pass
```

`file_2.py` tries to import member from `file_1.py`:

```py
# file_2.py
from dir_0.dir_1.file_1 import foo
```

But not absolute nor relative import seems work. How to do Python's imports correctly? If I could avoid using `sys.path.insert` it would be nice, but if there's no way around this then I guess that's how things stand.

Comment: Look at the `--editable` option of `pip`. You have to "install" your package in _Development Mode_. This will give you an idea how to restructure the layout of your project and package folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106602/4865723 But you also have to think about if a import structure like this make sense.

Comment: How do you execute `file_2.py`? The "simple" answer is that `dir_0` is not in a directory on Python's search path. Remember, the current working directory is not added to the search path on startup, only the directory containing the script.

Comment: Typically, you don't store your scripts in packages like this. Keep your scripts in `some_root`, and at most use them to call an entry point in an imported module.

Comment: "Real" installed scripts go somewhere like `/usr/bin`, and any packages get installed  somewhere like `/usr/lib/python/site-packages`. You only have import problems like this when trying to execute from source without installation.

Comment: It helps to make a clear distinction between files and modules (and directories and packages) when thinking about how the import system works. You don't import files and directories; you import packages and modules, and and the import system translates module names to file paths *when necessary*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Don't mess with the search path

You are right not messing around with `sys.path`. This is not recommended and always just an ugly workaround. There are better solutions for this.

## Restructure your folder layout

See [official Python docs about packaging](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Distinguish between *project folder* and *package folder*. We assume your `some_root` folder as the package folder which is also the name of the package (used in `import` statements). And it is recommended to put the package folder into a folder named `src`. Above it is the project folder `some_project`. This project folder layout is also known as the "Src-Layout".

In your case it should look like this.

```
some_project
└── src
    └── some_root
        ├── dir_0
        │   ├── dir_1
        │   │   ├── file_1.py
        │   │   └── __init__.py
        │   ├── dir_2
        │   │   ├── file_2.py
        │   │   └── __init__.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── __init__.py
```

## Make your package installable

Create a `some_project/setup.cfg` with that content. Keep the line breaks and indention in line 5 and 6. They have to be like this but I don't know why.

```
[metadata]
name = some_project

[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages = find:
zip_safe = False
python_requires = >= 3
[options.packages.find]
where = src
exclude =
    tests*
    .gitignore
```

Create `some_project/setup.py` with that content:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

## "Install" the package

This is not a usual installation. Please see [Developement Mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) to understand what this really means. The package is not copied into `/usr/lib/python/site-packages`; only links are created.

Navigate into the project folder `some_project` and run

```
python3 -m pip install --editable .
```

Don't forget the `.` at the end. Depending on your OS and environment maybe you have to replace `python3` with `py -3` or `python` or something else.

## Import

Your `file_2.py`

```
import some_root
import some_root.dir_0
import some_root.dir_0.dir_1
from some_root.dir_0.dir_1 import file_1

file_1.foo()
```

But as others said in the comments. Improve your structure of files and folders and reduce its complexity.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the Python search path includes directories that are effectively fixed when Python is installed: places like `/usr/lib/python/site-packages`.

When you run a script, the directory containing the script being executed is added to the path. Most importantly here, the current working directory is *not* added to the path, for security purposes. (You don't want your script to work differently, possibly importing modules you did not expect, based on its calling environment. This is the same reason it is strongly recommended to keep `.` out of your `PATH` variable.)

When you execute `file_2.py`, `some_root/dir_0/dir_2` is added to the path, but if `some_root` is the current working directory, `some_root` itself is not on the search path. That's why `import dir_0.dir_1.file_1` fails. A relative import fails as well because `some_root` is not the root (or any) package used to resolve the relative import.

Typically, if you wanted to run your code without installing it, you keep your scripts in `some_root` itself:

```
some_root/
  file_a.py
 
  - __init__.py
  - dir_0/
    - __init__.py
    - dir_1/
      - __init__.py
      - file_1.py
    - dir_2/
      - __init__.py
        file_2.py
```

`file_a.py` can be as simple as

```
from dir_0.dir_2.file_2 import main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with `file_2` providing an entry point rather than being directly executable itself. (It still *can* be executable itself; it just uses `main` the same as any other script importing `file_2.py` rather than just jumping straight into its code.)