# Python: Module Import Error for the billionth time

Tags: python

I can't believe after 8 years and 10,000 hours of using Python that I still get stumped by module import errors!!!!  My tree is as follows:

```
pcode
    /general
    /latin
        /latin
            v_reading.py
    /other
        add_path.py
        use_pydub.py
```

In the `add_path.py` module I add some modules to the `sys.path` like so:

```
import sys

vol='/users/me/'
gen_dir = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir)
gen_dir1 = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/byu_corpus/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir1)
gen_dir1 = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/latin/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir1)
gen_dir1 = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/latin/latin/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir1)
gen_dir1 = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/general/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir1)
gen_dir1 = f'{vol}Documents/pcode/other/'
sys.path.append(gen_dir1)
```

so when I run `sys.path` I get inter alia:

```
/Users/me/Documents/pcode/other
/users/me/documents/pcode/
/users/me/documents/pcode/latin/   ## I'm not sure if this is necessary but I did it anyway
/users/me/documents/pcode/latin/latin/
/users/me/documents/pcode/general/
/users/me/documents/pcode/other/
```

The first lines of the `use_pydub.py` module are as follows:

```
import sys
import add_path
from general import *
import latin
from latin.latin.v_reading import focus
```

I do not get an error when I run the module from pycharm but I do get the following error when I run it from command line:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'latin.latin'

I don't understand why I can import the 'latin' folder but not the 'latin.latin' folder.  I also tried renaming the second latin folder to latin2 but that did not help.  I should also point out that there is no difference between the sys.path generated by pycharm and the sys.path generated by command line.

Comment: does your `latin/latin` folder contain an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Kinda hard to see that folder structure when is not formatted

Comment: Right after `import latin`, add `print(latin.__file__)`. Is it the path you want? You've added multiple directories that either have a subdirectory called "latin" or perhaps a module named "latin.py". Which one is `import latin` supposed to pick? It seems like you have a package, so only put that package's directory in sys.path, not all of its subpackage directories.

Comment: Remove the code adding `Documents/pcode/latin/latin/` and you should be all set.

Comment: Today it [is recommend](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to use the `src` layout for your project folder. Please see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166679/4865723

Comment: I might be wrong here, but it seems to me you only want `pcode` is your `sys.path`, and none of its subfolders. When you do an import like `latin.latin`, it looks for a directory called `latin` in a folder in your `sys.path`, and then a directory called `latin` or a file called `latin.py` inside that `latin` folder. So neither `pcode/latin` nor `pcode/latin/latin` belong in your `sys.path`.

Comment: Python treats the top level executing script (always called `__main__`) differently than any modules or packages that are imported. So, how do you run `add_path.py`? Is it a top level script or is it imported? Scripts are not a part of packages. It looks like `pcode` is a package. Generally, you'd put pcode's parent in sys.path (or better yet, write a setup.py and install the thing). In your case, thats /Users/me/Documents, which is not a good candidate for a package directory. You likely need some restructuring.

Comment: Meant `use_pydub.py` in that last comment.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack `sys.path` (and requiring everyone to remember to import the path-adding module before anything else important... and what if you can't figure out how to import `add_path` from the current module?), please just *learn to use relative imports properly*. This is *especially* important if you are trying to package the program and make it installable from PyPI, because those paths **will not be valid on someone else's computer!** Imports in Python are *really not that hard*.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem by *correctly using relative imports*:

1. Delete `add_path.py`, as it will no longer be useful or relevant.
2. In `use_pydub.py`, the appropriate relative imports look like:

   ```
   import sys
   from ..general import *
   from .. import latin
   from ..latin.latin.v_reading import focus
   ```
3. [Ensure that `pcode` is a top-level package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764) when the code runs. If, for example, `use_pydub.py` is intended to be a top-level script, run it as a module instead, with the `-m` flag to Python. Alternately, have a top-level driver script that uses the `pcode` package appropriately.
4. Ensure that **the package** is on the module import path. This doesn't require hacking `sys.path`, in general. It requires starting the program from just outside `pcode`, in development; *or* you can simply rely on the fact that *installing the package, per the usual process* will put it into one of the default paths where Python looks for third-party libraries. (That's the **point** of all that packaging stuff, using PyPI and `pip` etc.)

These things are **especially** important if you want to package the code and upload it to PyPI for others to use. Absolute paths hacked into `sys.path` are not going to work on someone else's computer - with a different username, the code installed into who knows which Python installation located who knows where on the disk, etc. Hacking in relative paths is just clumsily reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  By using the advice of tdelaney I ran `print(latin.__file__)` I discovered that I was not importing the correct package and that I had earlier downloaded my own package from pypi and placed that package in the site_packages and one of those packages was named `latin`.  That packaged was interfering with importing of the desired package.  So thanks for the tip tdelaney.